# split join data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

## Objective

Join `DT1` (as `i` in `data.table`) to `DT2` given key(s) column(s), within each group of `DT2` specified by the `Date` column.

I cannot run `DT2[DT1, on = 'key']` as that would be incorrect since `key` column is repeated across the `Date` column, but unique within a single date.

## Reproducible example with a working solution

`DT3` is my expected output. Is there any way to achieve this without the `split` manoeuvre, which does not feel very `data.table`-y?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT1 <- data.table(
  Segment  = sample(paste0('S', 1:10), 100, TRUE), 
  Activity = sample(paste0('A', 1:5), 100, TRUE), 
  Value    = runif(100)
)
dates <- seq(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-11-30'), by = '1 day')
DT2 <- data.table(
  Date    = rep(dates, each = 5), 
  Segment = sample(paste0('S', 1:10), 3340, TRUE), 
  Total   = runif(3340, 1, 2)
)
rm(dates)
# To ensure that each Date Segment combination is unique
DT2 <- unique(DT2, by = c('Date', 'Segment'))
iDT2 <- split(DT2, by = 'Date')
iDT2 <- lapply(
  iDT2, 
  function(x) {
    x[DT1, on = 'Segment', nomatch = 0]
  }
)
DT3 <- rbindlist(iDT2, use.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: What about using `merge` function with keys `'Date'` and `'Segment'`?

Comment: `Date` does not exist in `DT1`. Hence, can't be used to merge

Comment: Sorry, I should have written merge by `'Segment'` (only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result with a cartesian `merge`:

```
DT4 <- merge(DT2,DT1,by='Segment',allow.cartesian = TRUE)
```

Here is the proof:

```
> all(DT3[order(Segment,Date,Total,Activity,Value),
          c('Segment','Date','Total','Activity','Value')] == 
      DT4[order(Segment,Date,Total,Activity,Value),
          c('Segment','Date','Total','Activity','Value')])

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, `allow.cartesian` does it.